Меняется ли в TeamViewer'е ID Пользователя при смене IP?
Сохраняется ли возможность какого-либо доступа на ПК с TeamViewer'а и всеми его вариантами этого самого доступа (Неконтролируемый через учётку или без учётки с Постоянным паролем и тд), если изменился IP и провайдер?. Или при смене IP и провайдера даётся новый ID или пароль или всё вместе?
